Schema Log azure , How can I join Requests and Traces table together for a query where code result is 500?
I need to create a query to find logs where I can see requests and traces together and analyse if User SQL input queries are wrong?
I could not find schéma over logs tables and how to join them ?
How I can do it ?
Simple query in Application Insight logs analytics

Usually, depending on your app, you can do that by using e.g. the operation_Id:
requests
| project timestamp, operation_Id, operation_Name, resultCode
| join (
   traces
   | project timestamp, operation_Id, message
) on operation_Id
| project timestamp, operation_Name, message, resultCode


I think operation_id are not the same between the 2 tables for me ?

Other options would be: traceId, spanId or operation_parentId.

what about if I want to find traces based on exceptions

Its the same thing. Join them together with one of the fields mentioned.

the solution was:
exceptions
| project exceptionTimestamp = timestamp, operation_Id, operation_Name, outerMessage, 
          exceptionCorrelationId = tostring(parse_json(customDimensions).correlationId), details
| join (
    traces
    | project traceTimestamp = timestamp, operation_Id, message, 
              traceCorrelationId = tostring(parse_json(customDimensions).correlationId)
) on $left.exceptionCorrelationId == $right.traceCorrelationId
| project exceptionCorrelationId, traceCorrelationId, traceTimestamp, exceptionTimestamp, 
          operation_Name, message, outerMessage, details
| where outerMessage contains "Execution Timeout Expired" and message contains "Executing query:"
| order by exceptionTimestamp desc


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
